# Rewrite data from one csv file to another based on condition from the second file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file, for-loop

I have 2 csv files.
The 1st one stores the data about people.The 2nd one stores one column of data with emails and phone numbers in this column (one row = phone number or email, not both).

The first one:

| Salutation | First name | Last name | Name | Phone | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Frau | Beat | Fischer | Beat Fischer | +41789963214 | afischer@bluewin.ch |
| Herr | Catrina | Richter | Catrina Richter | +41735109624 | info@koch.ch |

...etc

The second one:

| unsubscribed |
| --- |
| lisawilson@yahoo.com |
| samsullivan@hotmail.com |
| +41620984573 |
| carolmiller@gmail.com |
| +41428756309 |

...etc

What I need is to remove rows from the first file the phone number of which contains in the second file (but I can ignore the emails)

This is what I tried to do:

```
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('EMRG_ Database.csv',  newline='') as database, \
            open('EMRG_Unsubscribed.csv',  newline='') as unsubscribed, \
            open('EMRG_Updated_Database.csv', 'w', newline='') as updated_db:
        database_reader = csv.reader(database, delimiter=',')
        unsubscribed_reader = csv.reader(unsubscribed, delimiter=',')
        updated_writer = csv.writer(updated_db, delimiter=',')
        for unsubscribed_row in unsubscribed_reader:
            for db_row in database_reader:
                if db_row[4] == unsubscribed_row:
                    print("checkpoint")
                    continue
                updated_writer.writerow(db_row)
```

but the last print line does not execute. I am more than sure that I have phone numbers from the second file that matches the phone numbers from the first, I've checked that.

Comment: If the second CSV isn't too large (over a million entries or so), read this file first and add all phone numbers to a set in memory. Then read first file, check if each phone number is in the set and write the row to the output file or not.

Comment: One problem is that you can't iterate over a `csv.reader` multiple times because the file pointer is at end of file after first complete iteration over the file. You have to reset the pointer for the underlying file to begin with `seek` method.

Comment: @michaelButscheer, thank you, that helped! But now I have a new problem :D. The line `updated_writer.writerow(db_row)` keeps writing rows that is already in updated csv. Do you think it would be a good idea to use if-clause and read the updated csv file for dublicates every time before writing smth in it?

Comment: Are these duplicates already in the first input CSV file or are they appearing from nowhere?

Comment: @MichaelButscher, they appear because of nested loop. The logic in code is that it writes down in empty csv file (were I store updated info) all rows from the first file, that does not match phone number from second file. And it does it every iteration, so it creates dublicates. I hope, you understand what I'm trying to say

Comment: There shouldn't be a nested loop anymore. First loop should read phone numbers from second file and build the set and second loop **after that** should read from first file, check phone numbers and write to output file.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, oooh, I see. I've changed the code and it works! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` intersection for this:

```
with open('EMRG_ Database.csv',  newline='') as database, \
        open('EMRG_Unsubscribed.csv',  newline='') as unsubscribed, \
        open('EMRG_Updated_Database.csv', 'w', newline='') as updated_db:
    database_reader = csv.reader(database)
    is_unsubscribed = set(csv.reader(unsubscribed)).intersection
    updated_writer = csv.writer(updated_db)

    for db_row in database_reader:
        if not is_unsubscribed(row[4:5]):
                print("checkpoint")
                continue

        updated_writer.writerow(db_row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list of unsubscribed fits into memory, then this solution works.

```py
# Get a set of unsubscribed
with open("EMRG_Unsubscribed.csv") as stream:
    reader = csv.reader(stream)
    unsubscribed = set(
        row[0]
        for row in reader
        if "@" not in row[0]  # exclude email
    )

# Process and output
with open("EMRG_ Database.csv") as database, \
        open("EMRG_Updated_Database.csv", "w") as updated_database:
    
    reader = csv.reader(database)
    writer = csv.writer(updated_database)
    
    for row in reader:
        if row[4] not in unsubscribed:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Notes

- I use a set instead of list to store the list of unsubscribed. This has two advantages: faster look up and no duplications
- When building the set of unsubscribed, I exclude the emails to keep the size of the set smaller